# Set CSS animation keyframe attributes in Email html body content

Tags: html, css, html-email

I wanted to know if some of you have already tried to produce animated bliking text in email html body content.

As we know mail clients do not support **< style>** tag, it's not possible to set css animation keyframe attributes inline, because the animation should be declared. Like this :

```
 @keyframes colorblink { 
  0% { }
  50% { color:black; } 
 }
```

before being called.

How to achieve this for an email html body content? Or you think it's not possible at all?

Comment: Not possible.....

Comment: https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-design/css-animation-email/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the popular email clients do support `<style>`.

Campaign Monitor maintains a Web page of what is currently possible with major email clients and CSS.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

The animation is possible but it won't work everywhere. You can use progressive enhancement to target the environments that DO support it and load a static flat colour in all others.

This snippet allows you to target email clients running on Webkit (basically iOS devices)

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    /* Build animation CSS here */
}
```

iOS devices account for (very) roughly 25% of email opens, so you have to weigh up if it's worth the effort for your customer base or not.